# I can see and open file from index in apache but from address bar it gives me a file not found error? error log : not found or unable to stat 

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Here is my code snippet to go to the required page :Code to go to next page .

```
<a href="text.php?post_id=<?php echo "$postid"  + "$one" ; ?> ">NEXT </a><br/>
```

and the code of processing page that again return to the same page :

```
$postid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['post_id']);

$get_next_page = "SELECT post_title from posts where post_id ='$postid' ";
$confirm_next_page = @mysql_query($get_next_page) ;
if(!$confirm_next_page)
{
echo "<a href=\"javascript: history.go(-1)\">Back</a></h2>". mysql_error(); 
}
while($row =@mysql_fetch_array($confirm_next_page))
     {
    $redirect_page = "post.php?post_id=$postid&post_title=$post_title";
    header("location : $redirect_page ");
}
?>
```

when I execute this code I get 404 page not found .I have checked the permissons and they are set to read/write for me . If I go to index of / , it shows me a Back button as required and  this error :
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Thankx !

Comment: <?php echo "$postid" + "$one" ; ?>
this + shoudlnt be . ?
i mean : <?php echo "$postid" . "$one" ; ?>
would you please provide us the full url (including the file name and query string ) when you get a 404 error ?

Comment: actually I have declared $one = 1 cause I want to get the next post . If I use only 1 , i get some different errors :) .

Comment: your code contains some  syntax  errors that must make fatal erros , such as unexpected '}' on line 13.
$next_page is not defined , so this may cause you getting a 404 page not found

Comment: QUERY string shown in address bar : http://127.0.0.1/htdocs/text.php?post_id=153                                                                                                                        error I get :The requested URL /htdocs/text.php was not found on this server.

Comment: have you tried this ? : 127.0.0.1/text.php?post_id=153

Comment: although my file is in htdocs I still tried it and get 404 .

Comment: this means that you are runnig the file with a wrong address, after fixing the errors mentioned above your file worked successfully on my local . call this 127.0.0.1 on your browser and follow your file by clicking the folder and then file name , i cant guess the exact address but im some how sure that the requesting address is wrong .
hope to help

Comment: well , it still says 404 when I click the link generated by processing page . It says   not found or enable to stat in error log . I know it`s there cause I can see and open it . Thankx anyway .

Answer (score 1):

Ok, 404 means that the server is unable to find the file you're looking for. (404 literally means [file not found](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)). If you are getting this error, it means that you have probably mis-typed the name of the file. To be sure, however, you may wish to make sure that there are no `.htaccess` files or the like in the directory you're working in -- those can cause problems, but my experience is that bad `.htaccess` results in a 500 because it involves a redirect resulting in a 404

The reason you're getting that MySQL error is probably because you have entered the url correctly, but you have omitted the `post_id` parameter. If this is the case, that means that you have turned your error reporting down below maximum. I highly recommend that you turn them back on high.